# Is $\mathbb{C^2}$ a vector space over $\mathbb{C}$ if multiplication is defined $k(z,w)=(k \overline z, \overline kw)$?

Tags: linear-algebra, vector-spaces, complex-numbers

I'm not sure but it looks like if multiplication is defined as $k(z,w)=(k \overline z, \overline kw)$ then neutral member doesn't exist.

If $z=a+ib$, $w=c+id$ then:
$$
1(z,w) = (1 \overline z, \overline 1w)=((a-ib),(c+id)) \neq (z,w)
$$

I assume that the reciprocal of a real number is itself, e.g. $\overline 5=5$

Comment: You proved it yourself that it cannot be a vector space

Answer (score 1, accepted):

An easier way to see it is with the element $(i,i)$. Suppose $k$ is a multiplicative identity, then $(i,i) = k(i,i) = (k\overline{i},\overline{k}i)$. Thus $-ki = i$ so $-k = 1$, i.e. $k=-1$. However we also have that $\overline{k}i = i$, so $\overline{k} = 1$ and so $k = 1$. These contradict each other, so there is no multiplicative identity.

Note that you cannot assume that $1$ is a multiplicative identity.

Comment: You're saying that I can't assume that $1$ is neutral member of the vector space for multiplication right?

Comment: Correct. If you muck up your scalar multiplication, $1$ need not still be the multiplicative identity.

Comment: That's a great tip, I didn't realize that

Comment: Actually, the multiplicative identity $1_F$ of the base field $F$ must always act as identity for the scalar product of a vector space $V$ over $F$, because the vector space axioms dictate that the scalar product must be associative. Indeed, suppose that $k \in F$ acts as identity, i.e. $k \mathbf{v} = \mathbf{v}$ for every $\mathbf{v} \in V$. Then $\mathbf{v} = k \mathbf{v} = (1_F \cdot k) \mathbf{v} = 1_F(k \mathbf{v}) = 1_F \mathbf{v}$, so $1_F$ acts as identity, too.